# Store the result of an UPDATE with a RETURNING clause on PLPGSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In a plpgsql function I need to do several checks, and return some values based on those checks.

I can perform a `SELECT INTO v_variable column FROM table` but what I need to store is not the result of a `SELECT` rather a result of an `UPDATE table SET column = new_value RETURNING check`

Is there a way to store this check in a variable to later us it, or just an `OUT` variable so this value is returned by the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it `SELECT`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. When you specify `RETURNING` it works the same way as it was `SELECT`. So you can write:

```
UPDATE table SET column = new_value RETURNING check INTO <your_variable>
```

More to that, you can use the results in the same query with the help of CTE:

```
WITH updated AS (
    UPDATE table SET column = new_value RETURNING check
)
SELECT check FROM updated ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the value from the `RETURNING` clause in a variable using `INTO`, just as for `SELECT`:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = new_value
RETURNING check INTO my_variable
```